Java API Comparator JSON Parser
I'm working on a project that involves comparing responses from two different REST APIs. These APIs receive the same request, but I need to verify if the JSON responses are identical.
I want to pinpoint the specific tags with differing values if there are any discrepancies. Also, is there any time delay in the execution time?
This comparison needs to be done periodically for a significant number of APIs, making manual checks infeasible.
I'm looking to automate this process using Java. I believe a custom API comparator program could be a good solution.
Here's what I'm hoping to achieve:

Send the same request to two separate REST APIs. Parse the JSON
responses from both APIs. Compare the parsed JSON structures to
identify any differences. If differences exist, pinpoint the specific
tags (keys) with different values. Track the time taken for each
execution

My questions are:
What's the best approach for comparing nested JSON structures efficiently?
How can I effectively handle potential errors during API calls or JSON parsing?
I've done some initial research and found some resources on using libraries like Apache HttpClient and Jackson for making HTTP requests and parsing JSON.
However, I'd appreciate any insights or guidance from the community on building a robust and efficient API comparator .

Here is a post about comparing JSON data using Java libraries: How to compare JSON documents and return the differences with Jackson or Gson?


My questions are: What's the best approach for comparing nested JSON structures efficiently? How can I effectively handle potential errors during API calls or JSON parsing?

 How to do testing?
When trying to test an application that communicates with other services, then we could do one of two things:

deploy all microservices and perform end to end tests

mock other microservices in unit / integration tests


Both have their advantages but also a lot of disadvantages.
 Deploy all microservices and perform end to end tests
Advantages:

simulates production

tests real communication between services


Disadvantages:

to test one microservice we would have to deploy 6 microservices, a couple of databases etc.

the environment where the tests would be conducted would be locked for a single suite of tests (i.e. nobody else would be able to run the tests in the meantime).

long to run

very late feedback

extremely hard to debug


Mock other microservices in unit / integration tests
Advantages:

very fast feedback

no infrastructure requirements


Disadvantages:

the implementor of the service creates stubs thus they might have nothing to do with the reality

you can go to production with passing tests and failing production


Reference: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-contract


If you are Deploy all microservices and perform end to end tests then you can use the JSON Assert library

Example:
final String json = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
final String expected = "{field:'value', anotherField:true}";

JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, json, true);

Where you are actually calling your endpoint and retrieving the response.

If you are mocking the infrastructure, you can

Example:
final MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                                .andDo(print())
                                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                                .andReturn();

final String json = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
final String expected = "{field:'value', anotherField:true}";

JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, json, true); 


